# Sorting divs based on index using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am sorting 3 divs based on the position they are currently in. The sorting works fine but I am struggling to get the index value for each div.

The problem is,

- when I click (down arrow) for div 2 it gives me the index value 0 where as it should give me 1.
- If I click div 3 (up arrow) it gives
  me 0 instead of 2

Html code:

```
<div class="flow-container">
  <div class="flow-block">
    <div class="sort-arrows">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-up" id="sort-up"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-down" id="sort-down"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flow-content" data-key="2yqz1jpdxwy2g434zyo8r7k6vml9n50d">
      <h3 class="bg-primary">Div 1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flow-block">
    <div class="sort-arrows">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-up" id="sort-up"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-down" id="sort-down"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flow-content" data-key="q2qlvpm98n7d2kejzx3g5jy41r6wzx0p">
      <h3 class="bg-primary">Div 2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flow-block">
    <div class="sort-arrows">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-up" id="sort-up"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-down" id="sort-down"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flow-content" data-key="q2qlvpm98n7d2kejzx3g5jy41r6wzx0p">
      <h3 class="bg-primary">Div 3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/gvyoj63a/2/

Any help if highly appreciated.

Comment: You are using the same id's for each of the sort-up / sort-down spans. Each Id needs to be unique.

Comment: Yes right. I will give unique ids. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var pos = $(this).parent().index();
```

into

```
var pos = $(this).closest('.flow-block').index();
```

As .parent() selects the div which contains the up and down arrows.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for getting the index is selecting the div group that's wrapping the arrows, not the item div.

try something like:

```
var pos = $(this).parent().parent().index();
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. Understood now. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner code

```
$("body").on('click tap', '.fa-arrow-down, .fa-arrow-up', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elem = $(this).closest(".flow-block");
  var pos = elem.index();
  alert(pos);
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-arrow-down')) {
    elem.next().after(elem);
  } else {
    elem.prev().before(elem);
  }
});
```